# Is there a way to join a couple of columns using a R function?

Tags: r

I have columns `Name` in list.x and `Name`,`Suburb` in list.y. I am willing to join them list.x and list.y. The problem is, `Name` in list.x is,

1. `Name` in list.x separated by `!` whereas in list.y separated by `,`
2. `Name` in list.x First name then last na,e `!` whereas in list.y Last name then First name.

```
list.x = data.frame(
         Name = c("John!Citizen","Dipayan!Banerjee","Smith!Langley!White"))

list.y = data.frame(
Name = c("White,Smith,Langley","Citizen,John","Banerjee,Dipayan"),
Suburb = c("Langley","Mars","Here"))
```

I want to match `x.list` with `y.list` by `Product` and `Molecule`

Comment: What is the expected output?  Please show it precisely.

Comment: For now, I am looking for a way to map the files, I can then leverage the function. Ideally, I will have other columns in y.list, that will get mapped when matching with "Product and Molecule"

Answer (score 1):

```
orderAlp<-function(x){
  str_split(x, ' ') %>% lapply(x, 'sort') %>%  lapply(x, 'paste', collapse=' ') %>% unlist(x)
}
x.list %>% full_join(y.list,by="Product") %>% 
  mutate(Moleculs.x=str_replace_all(Moleculs.x,"!",","),
         Molecules.y=orderAlp(Molecules.y))
```

I wish to add output here but the obs name so long and I couldn't add it.

Comment: Thanks Fatih Ekici. You solution will work, but the reason I wan to use Molecule in the "by ="  as a second condition, because instance when a Same product will have different Molecule.

Comment: you can add joining function 
full_join(y.list, by = c("Product","Moleculs.x"="Molecules.y"))

For more joining info https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html
But if you joining by two groups You must synchronize the values ​​in the columns first. you can simply use function ı given that.

Comment: Hi Fatih, I believe at you end the function is running with any error. However, I am unbale to run the function and getting error, Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Molecules.y`.
x object 'x' of mode 'function' was not found
i Input `Molecules.y` is `orderAlp(Molecules.y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x.list %>%
  separate_rows(Moleculs.x, sep = '!') %>%
  rename(Molecules =  Moleculs.x) %>%
  inner_join(y.list %>%
               separate_rows(Molecules.y, sep = ',') %>%
               rename(Molecules = Molecules.y), by = c("Product", "Molecules")) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thanks for the solution, but apart from separator, some Molecules are not in order. Take a look in this one

Comment: Molecule.x = CYANOCOBALAMIN!DEXPANTHENOL!NICOTINAMIDE!PYRIDOXINE!RIBOFLAVIN!THIAMINE

Comment: Molecule.y = NICOTINAMIDE,PYRIDOXINE,DEXPANTHENOL,THIAMINE,RIBOFLAVIN,CYANOCOBALAMIN

Comment: Join does not require elements to be in order.

Comment: Hi Ronak, to elaborate my question, list.x = data.frame(Name = c("John Citizen","Dipayan Banerjee"))

list.y = data.frame(Name = c("Citizen John","Banerjee Dipayan"),
                    Suburb = c("Langley","Mars"))

Comment: How would you join on the two name, from list.x and list.y. in list.x it is First name then last name, whereas, list.y is Last name then First name.